# Adding href in a return confirm

Tags: javascript, html, popup, href

Trying to add a link in a return confirm

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Before downloading the App please make sure that you have read our polices');">[...]
```

The policies at the end should be a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can only add plaintext to the native javascript confirm function.

You might want to use a jquery plugin or something like that which gives you the ability to have custom dialog windows.

Jquery UI : https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Or twitter bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/